# how to make Soong and Kati translate ninja rules in parallel?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, ninja, android-soong

Android build system has Soong and Kati where:

- Soong translates `.bp` file to `.ninja` files
- Kati translates `.mk` files to `.ninja` files

When profiling the AOSP build time with *soong_ui*, I saw these translation processes occurred sequentially which I don't think is necessary? - Is that possible to make the two translation process run in parallel?

Cited from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/perf.md):
[image: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/perf.md]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out it's not always feasible to run Soong and Kati in parallel at least at the current stage with Android 10. The reason being a .mk file can depend on a .bp file so Soong has to translate those dependency .bp first before Kati can translate all .mk files to generate build rules.